# Where are my applications. Clarify using help pages

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

We have great documentation for how to use SO/SE sites but not a lot of docs on using the jobs portion.  First request is we need some documentation on how this all works.

Especially things like applications.  I clicked on messages and then applications hoping to see the applications that I have applied for.  The query behind this is not returning applications.  All it shows is:

> Bummer.  There isnt anything to show right now.

To me I would have hoped to see my pending applications?  Or at least a status of them.  How does this page even work?

[image]

Comment: Try clicking on Sent -> Applications.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas - When is the case I would have an application in my inbox - when an employer is after me?  Doesn't that come in the form of a message?  This is pretty confusing, I would have never guessed.

Comment: @JonH While I don't agree with the decision, it's by design. That's where any responses to a submitted application will show up. I agree with you though, doesn't make a lot of sense.